# How are the turquoise / blue sea and warm sand tones achieved in this photograph?

Tags: color, color-correction

It seems as if the white isn't really white, but then also the lowtones seem special.
I love the way everything looks so warm, but at the same time the blue is blue.

**Any idea how this artist achieved these kind of color corrections?**

[image]

Comment: The shadows are illuminated by skylight, exclusively, so it is understandable that they would appear blue. The whole scene is illuminated by daylight, a combination of sunlight and skylight.

Comment: Can I ask for the source you got this image from?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if the red-cyan contrast has been increased to the extent that the subtler coloration of everything in the image has been pushed towards one of those poles. In particular, the shadows, which would normally be a duller sky-blue color, are distinctly cyan, while the sand and anything else in the image that had any red value at all is now *very* red. The image seems to be more or less white-balanced for the sunlight (no strong cast to the white sunlit areas).

Answer (score 1):

I imagine, there is some post-processing in there.

Also, from the shadows, I can see that it is near the [Golden Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hour_(photography)), which render the scene in more warmer tones.

Comment: The shadows look blue-ish. That's probably a lot of post processing. Although the feeling is warm in the image, the sea itself is not gold-blue. it's very deep blue.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like they simply played with the Hue/Sat sliders in Lightroom.

The Cyans/Blues may have been tweaked in hue, but they have definitely been upped in Saturation and (potentially) some Luminance as well.

Same with the Orange/Red/Yellow values. I would have expected the beach to be a bit more white/yellow/brown. The Golden Hour + a slight Hue adjustment and an increase in Sat could account for the strong Red presence.

I suppose a split tone in color balance could have been applied - applying a cool value to the shadows and a warm value to the highlights - but this isn't noticeable in the ocean highlights, meaning it would have been masked out. I don't hold a lot of hope for this technique being used, but it is possible.

tl;dr - it's probably just a bump in Contrast, Sat, and Lum values along with some slight Hue changes.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Hue or Levels per each color channel shifted in Photoshop. It takes 5 seconds in Hue/Saturation dialog box of many photo editors. Alternatively green channel substituted with contents of the blue or vice versa.